# fix for a gap in IE for an image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, image, doctype

I have read the answers posted for this issue and tried them all, but still have the gap.  See link to the site I am working on http://www.poolboy.ca/.  It's the gap between the top of the pool and the menu bar. Please help!

Comment: What version of IE? IE8 has no gap

Comment: Does your webpage do a css reset? That may help alleviate any presets the browsers have

Answer (score 4):

There's a really easy fix here.

Your doctype (first line) is currently this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

That doctype triggers [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in IE.

If you change your doctype to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

IE will be in Standards Mode instead, and your gap will magically disappear.

You could instead just use the HTML5 doctype, which is much shorter:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: That fixed it! That was driving me crazy,  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

add to your css i cant promise anything but this will set all boxes to have 0px margin padding and border by default this is something i can not fathom about ie but it normally fixes it

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}
```